# Cyclic/Seasonal cubic spline

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, statsmodels, cubic-spline

I would like to fit a cubic spline to a time series that is seasonal i.e. integrating the day of the year in the independent variables. I have been looking at scipy and statsmodels but I have found no examples as to how to apply them when the data is seasonal. Does anyone have an example/piece of code I could use, please?